# Basic java array element comparision not working correctly

Tags: java, arrays

Im creating a program which, for each array element , returns the number of elements in the array which are smaller than the array element.

The program works perfectly until it says that 2 > 2 which is false when the program is run.

I can't see where i went wrong in the code.

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution a = new Solution();
    int nums[] = {8,1,2,2,3};
    a.smallerNumbersThanCurrent(nums);

}
 public int[] smallerNumbersThanCurrent(int[] nums) {
       for(int i=0; i<nums.length ; i++){
           int counter = 0;
           for(int j =0; j<nums.length; j++){
             int a = nums[j];
             int b = nums[i];
             if((b>a) && (a !=b) && (i !=j)) {
                 counter++;
                 System.out.print(b +" is bigger than "+ j +" ");
                 System.out.println("Counter =" + counter + " Array[" + i + "] is bigger than array[" + j+ "]");
             }
           }
           nums[i] = counter;
       }
        return nums;
    }
```

}

Comment: I also don't see anything wrong in your code, but your print statement is "b is bigger than j"... is this what you want? shouldn't it be b is bigger than a?

Comment: Why don't you change the print statement to see the values of a, b, i, and j?

Comment: (b>a) && (a !=b) could be simplified to just b>a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code to make it work correctly.  I was a bit confused on a couple of things you have:

```
`if((b>a) && (a !=b) && (i !=j))`
```

a !=b and i !=j is redundant, so i'd remove the i!=j from the if statement

then you have this:

```
nums[i] = counter;
```

I honestly can't figure out why this line is in your code, but you end up changing you values in the middle of the first for loop with it.  It is also what is causing your issue.
here is slightly edited code that I believe gives you the proper output

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution a = new Solution();
    int nums[] = {8,1,2,2,3};
    a.smallerNumbersThanCurrent(nums);
    }

 public int[] smallerNumbersThanCurrent(int[] nums) {
       for(int i=0; i<nums.length ; i++){
           int counter = 0;
           for(int j =0; j<nums.length; j++){
             int a = nums[j];
             int b = nums[i];
             if((b>a) && (a != b)) {
                 counter++;
                 System.out.print(b +" is bigger than "+ j +" ");
                 System.out.println("Counter =" + counter + " Array[" + i + "] is bigger than array[" + j+ "]");
             }
           }
       }
        return nums;
    }
}
```

the output now reads:

```
8 is bigger than 1 Counter =1 Array[0] is bigger than array[1]
8 is bigger than 2 Counter =2 Array[0] is bigger than array[2]
8 is bigger than 3 Counter =3 Array[0] is bigger than array[3]
8 is bigger than 4 Counter =4 Array[0] is bigger than array[4]
2 is bigger than 1 Counter =1 Array[2] is bigger than array[1]
2 is bigger than 1 Counter =1 Array[3] is bigger than array[1]
3 is bigger than 1 Counter =1 Array[4] is bigger than array[1]
3 is bigger than 2 Counter =2 Array[4] is bigger than array[2]
3 is bigger than 3 Counter =3 Array[4] is bigger than array[3]
```